# Change a homepage based on theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 themes in my WP installation: `Theme`, `Theme2`, and separately I have 2 Homepages, one for each theme.

Is it any way for me to change a homepage based on active theme dynamically?

So, Example if i'll activate `Theme2`, Homepage2 becomes a main homepage?

Ideally, i want something like:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    switch_theme('twentytwelve');
    /* Activate Homepage_1 */
  } else {
    switch_theme('twentythirteen');
    /* Activate Homepage_2 */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change a homepage based on theme wordpress**

You can follow this steps and set the homepage page as you have activated the theme.

1. Click on “Pages” from your dashboard.
2. Click the “Add New” button on the top and create a new page called, “Homepage.”
3. Go to “Settings” from the dashboard, and click on “Reading.”
4. The first option available is called “Front Page Displays.” Change it to “A static page.”
5. In the “Front Page” drop down, you should see your new homepage. Select it and save your changes.
6. Go back into “Pages” and click on your homepage.
7. Add the shortcodes you want to display.
8. Update your homepage.